# Google cloud messaging client side registering

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am continulously getting Service not available error while trying to register for the application..it worked a few days but not every time.
I am actually calling the register method through a async call and in that a new thread.
is this correct or any suggestions..
please help as i struggling from maybe 3 weeks on this.

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You are using the new gcm api or the depreciated one?

Comment: May be connectivity problem ?